# write a mvc framework to learn struts

Tags: model-view-controller, struts2

Hi:
I am learning struts,however I was often confused by its configuration,sometimes I do know clearly why.

SO I wonder if there is any idea to write a simple mvc framework which need not have to be prowerful enough,just make me know more about the steps the struts-like framework do.

Any ideas?

Comment: I did not understand what you actually want. 1.do you want to know how an mvc framework works(as in components) or 2)do you want to how mvc is implemented in struts or 3)you want to make a simple mvc structure for you ur web-app by yourself without framework

Comment: I am trying use the framework-struts2,but I found I can use it easily.So I want to know how a mvc framework work,and i thinkd write a simple mvc-like framework may help me use it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC is really a paradigm, and if you simply want to get up an running with an mvc framework,  you can look into groovy on grails (which is built on spring mvc) and should be easy to understand and quickly configure

If you want to be adventurous, you can play with django, which is the python framework for building web apps, though they prescribe to the mvp (model view presenter) pattern.

Additionally, http://www.springsource.org/roo may be a good fit for pure Java fans

Comment: groovy ?AFAIK,it is a programmic language??

Comment: sorry, I meant groovy on grails!

Answer (score 0):

Also, there is the Struts 2 tutorials which help.

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/getting-started.html

I enjoy the "Bootstrap tutorials" which is a link at the bottom of the aforementioned page.